# listing files with extension in Terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line

in a Terminal session the command

```
ls *.pdf -l
```

does not list the pdfs (or whatever other file format) as expected, as the -l option seems to be ignored. Everything works fine if I issue a simple

```
ls -l
```

How do I fix this? 
I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.5 and using a bash shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the `-l` flag before the other arguments, like this:

```
ls -l *.pdf
```

Comment: Just to expand, arguments should always precede the object of the command: `command -> arguments -> object` unless the `man` pages indicate that certain arguments need to follow the object.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I was pretty sure it was different in Ubuntu, but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @FredS: It is. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12722/porting-linux-shell-scripts?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you want `ls` (and other commands) feeling like on a linux system, you should install [homebrew](http://brew.sh) by typing:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

In order the `ls` command to work like you said, after installing homebrew, you need the [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils) package.

```
brew install coreutils
```

After that, you will use like you want.